# Map service query regarding old version of SQL Server client communications

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, map-service, arcgis-10.4

I just upgraded to ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 on my ArcGIS Server machine. I could not connect via an SDE connection at first but I uninstalled the 2008 SQL Native Client and installed Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server (we also just upgraded to SQL Server 2014 a few weeks ago) on our ArcGIS Server machine and the SDE connection worked fine after that.

However, I tried a query on our map services and get the error regarding the old client (see screenshot). I did the same thing on the web server machine (uninstalled 2008 and installed ODBC Driver 13), but it's still not working. Do you think I should just uninstall all references to 2008? I'm not sure why all those SQL Server 2008 program files are installed on our web server since we have a separate machine for SQL Server as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However I have 2014 installed. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I have updated my comment to an answer with a bit more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [SQL Server Native Client 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) (In that link hit the + next to "Install Instructions" and search for Native Client).

Quick link to download files:

- [SQL Server Native Client 2012 x32](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239647&clcid=0x409)
- [SQL Server Native Client 2012 x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409)

These are the files [Microsoft suggest to use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280510(v=sql.120).aspx) if you still require the Native Client after 2012 (e.g. for your 2014 installation):

> The OLE DB Provider in SQL Server Native Client was last updated in SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Developers who wish to use an OLE DB provider to connect to the latest version of SQL Server must use the OLE DB provider that shipped in SQL Server 2012 Native Client.

I have had no issues with Desktop, SDE, or Server after updating the Native Client to 2012, and have eliminated similar messages in our ArcGIS installs.

Comment: Thank you! I first installed this on my web server and it still did not work. However, I then installed on my ArcGIS Server machine and it worked!